# Inconsistent operand constraints Android NDK

Tags: android, c, assembly, android-ndk

I've been trying to compile a C library but I'm getting this error from the math library
I'm compiling using the Android NDK r13b and android API 21 as a sysroot

```
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:769:3: error: inconsistent operand     
constraints in an 'asm'
   __asm __volatile ("fnstcw %3\n\t"           \
   ^
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:503:5: note: in definition of macro '__inline_mathcodeNP_'
     code;              \
     ^
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:764:1: note: in expansion of macro '__inline_mathcodeNP'
 __inline_mathcodeNP (ceil, __x, \
```

The full code is here ...

```
__inline_mathcodeNP (floor, __x, \
  register long double __value;                           \
  register int __ignore;                              \
  unsigned short int __cw;                            \
  unsigned short int __cwtmp;                             \
  __asm __volatile ("fnstcw %3\n\t"                       \
            "movzwl %3, %1\n\t"                       \
            "andl $0xf3ff, %1\n\t"                    \
            "orl $0x0400, %1\n\t"   /* rounding down */       \
            "movw %w1, %2\n\t"                        \
            "fldcw %2\n\t"                        \
            "frndint\n\t"                         \
            "fldcw %3"                            \
            : "=t" (__value), "=&q" (__ignore), "=m" (__cwtmp),       \
              "=m" (__cw)                         \
            : "0" (__x));                         \
  return __value)

__inline_mathcodeNP (ceil, __x, \
  register long double __value;                           \
  register int __ignore;                              \
  unsigned short int __cw;                            \
  unsigned short int __cwtmp;                             \
  __asm __volatile ("fnstcw %3\n\t"                       \
            "movzwl %3, %1\n\t"                       \
            "andl $0xf3ff, %1\n\t"                    \
            "orl $0x0800, %1\n\t"   /* rounding up */         \
            "movw %w1, %2\n\t"                        \
            "fldcw %2\n\t"                        \
            "frndint\n\t"                         \
            "fldcw %3"                            \
            : "=t" (__value), "=&q" (__ignore), "=m" (__cwtmp),       \
              "=m" (__cw)                         \
            : "0" (__x));                         \
  return __value)
```

I am using arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.9 for my compiler and obviously compiling for ARM android ... Thank you for reading and have a nice day

Edit: I realise this is a question that already exists, but what makes me really wonder is the fact that it happens on the standard math libraries, not even on my own or a 3rd party library

Edit2: Upon more research I found that bits/mathinline is nowhere to be found in the android NDK, which is odd ...

Comment: The code you've shown contains Intel x86 assembly so it appears there's something wrong with your build process if you're only trying to build for ARM.

Comment: I assumw I would have to find the same library headers but for android

Comment: @RossRidge It seems the actual file is nowhere to be found in the android ndk

Comment: [bits/mathinline.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/jb-dev/sysroot/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h) starts with a statement: *"Never use <bits/mathinline.h> directly; include <math.h> instead."*